# Не подключается MediatR .net

Tags: asp.net-core, c#-7.0

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такой код в сборке с коммандами:

```
public static class DependencyInjection
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddApplication(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var assembly = typeof(DependencyInjection).Assembly;

            services.AddMediatR(configuration =>
                configuration.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(assembly));

            return services;
        }
    };
```

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services
.AddApplication()
.AddInfrastructure();
```